# Comparing csv files in Powershell using Compare-Object

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I am new to powershell and I having a little dilemma with a script I created to compare two csv files.  The first csv has only one column called "Database Name" in it.  The secound csv has a many columns and I only care about two of them "Database Name" and "Host Name".  Right now the script  compares only the  "Database Name" column which works great!! and exports to Differences.csv.  However, I would also like to see the corresponding "Hostname" column for each "Database Name" in the difference file.

```
$northdb = Import-Csv -Path ".\northdb.csv" -Header "Database Name" | Sort-object Property "Database Name" -Unique 

$sdb = Import-Csv ".\Current\SQLDatabaseInventory.csv" -Header "hostname",h2,h3,h4,h5,"Database Name"  |Sort-Object -Property "Database Name" -Unique

Compare-Object $northdb $sdb -Property  "Database Name" |  Where-Object{$_.SideIndicator -eq '=>'} | 
Select-Object  "Database Name" | export-csv .\Difference.csv -NoTypeInfo
```

Please assist

Comment: can you share some sample data from both files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you add the `-PassThru` to your compare object you'll receive all the object properties

```
Compare-Object $northdb $sdb -Property  "Database Name" -PassThru
```

Then you can also export hostname :

```
Compare-Object $northdb $sdb -Property  "Database Name" -PassThru |  Where-Object{$_.SideIndicator -eq '=>'} | Select-Object  "Database Name", "hostname" | export-csv .\Difference.csv -NoTypeInfo
```