# powershell :extract inputobject data from compare-object while comparing 2 csv

Tags: csv, powershell, compare, output

I am simply comparing 2 .csv files using compare-object with two fields of data and I am getting the expected results but the output format is just different . 
How do I extract the information from the results?

```
Compare-Object   $list1 $list -IncludeEqual  |Where-Object { $_.SideIndicator -eq '<=' }    | ft *
InputObject                                                   SideIndicator
"ABC123","4/11/2016 9:06:01 AM"                                    <=           
"XYZ456","4/11/2016 10:21:40 AM"                                   <=           
"FOO789","4/11/2016 10:12:43 AM"                                   <=
```

How can I extract individual csv values from this output ?

Comment: You need to restore the inputobject that you see on the screen here. `Compare-Object   $list1 $list -IncludeEqual  |Where-Object { $_.SideIndicator -eq '<=' } | Select-Object -ExpandProperty INputObject`

Comment: @Matt , its getting better but its still showing both fields in one output 
"ABC123","4/11/2016 9:06:01 AM" , how can I get this split without usingsplit() to get results like "ABC123"       "4/11/2016 9:06:01 AM" , I mean separate.

Comment: We need to see how you populate the `$lists`. Get-Content or Import-CSV?

Comment: This might have your answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19040159/comparing-csv-files-in-powershell-using-compare-object

Comment: @Matt Lesson learned , I was using get-content with csv , BAD IDEA ! 
With CSV one should use import-csv. Thanks for pointing that out.